# Sharing Cakephp session

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

Is it possible to share cakephp session between cake applications of different version.I have two applications having cake1.3 and cake2.3 respectively.Kindly answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's possible using database sessions. You need to create a database table:

```
CREATE TABLE cake_sessions (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  data text,
  expires int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

And in core.php (CakePHP 2.x) set:

```
// Location /app/Config/core.php
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'database'
));
```

On CakePHP 1.3, set:

```
// Location /app/config/core.php
Configure::write('Session.save', 'database');
```

Comment: in which database I can create this table, and how to make this table from another application?